# Is there a good jQuery plugin or JS code for time durations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, time

I basically want to produce the following:

from int 67 to 1 minute 7 seconds

from int 953 to 15 minutes 53 seconds

from int 3869 to 1 hour 4 minutes 29 seconds

pseudo code:

```
// original
<span class="time">67</span>

//output
<span class="time">1 minute 7 seconds</span>

// js
$('.time').format_duration();
```

Comment: I think this is more of a JavaScript question than a jQuery question. What you're asking for really falls out of the scope of what jQuery is for...

Comment: You are probably right, but figured I would make it jquery related in the case of an available plugin ... I'm starting to code something now, but im sure this code is available somewhere ...

Comment: Actually, if I remember there was a blog post about hoe SO generates its timestamps in a "human-friendly" way... I thought there was some source code that would be useful there but I can't seem to find it now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Borrowing most of Guffa's answer, this should do the trick as a jQuery plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.time_from_seconds = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var t = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
        $(this).data('original', t);
        var h = Math.floor(t / 3600);
        t %= 3600;
        var m = Math.floor(t / 60);
        var s = Math.floor(t % 60);
        $(this).text((h > 0 ? h + ' hour' + ((h > 1) ? 's ' : ' ') : '') +
                     (m > 0 ? m + ' minute' + ((m > 1) ? 's ' : ' ') : '') +
                     s + ' second' + ((s > 1) ? 's' : ''));
    });
};
```

If you have HTML like this:

```
<span class='time'>67</span>
<span class='time'>953</span>
<span class='time'>3869</span>
```

And you call it like this:

```
$('.time').time_from_seconds();
```

The HTML is turned to:

```
<span class="time">1 minute 7 seconds</span>
<span class="time">15 minutes 53 seconds</span>
<span class="time">1 hour 4 minutes 29 seconds</span>
```

Each element also has a [data attribute](http://docs.jquery.com/Data) of 'original' with the seconds it originally contained.

My answer directly answers your question, but I'm going to take a shot in the dark: if you want to show how long ago something happened in human time (ie, "5 minutes ago") there is the [jQuery timeago plugin](http://timeago.yarp.com/) for this. I don't think it accepts seconds as the format, though. It has to be a [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date.

Answer (score 6):

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>

var tbl = [
    [ 7*24*60*60, 'week' ],
    [ 24*60*60, 'day' ],
    [ 60*60, 'hour' ],
    [ 60, 'minute' ],
    [ 1, 'second' ]
];

function convert() {
    var t = parseInt($('#val').val());
    var r = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < tbl.length; i++) {
        var d = tbl[i];
        if (d[0] < t) {
            var u = Math.floor(t / d[0]);
            t -= u * d[0];
            r += u + ' ' + d[1] + (u == 1 ? ' ' : 's ');
        }
    }
    $('#result').html(r);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id='val' type='text' size='10' />
<input type='button' value='convert' onclick='convert()' />
<div id='result' />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Give the element an id so that it's easy to access:

```
<span id="time">67</span>
```

Now you can get the value and convert it:

```
var o = document.getElementById('time');
var t = parseInt(o.innerHTML);
var h = Math.floor(t / 3600);
t %= 3600;
var m = Math.floor(t / 60);
var s = t % 60;
o.innerHTML =
   (h > 0 ? h + ' hours ' : '') +
   (m > 0 ? m + ' minutes ' : '') +
   s + ' seconds';
```

Edit:
Added Math.floor() as suggested by Mike B.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you're looking for something more concise, and want to avoid the trailing whitespace and incorrect pluralization issues of some of the other attempts:

```
function timeString( t ) {
    var ret = [], t = {
        hour: parseInt(t/3600),
        minute: parseInt(t/60%60),
        second: t%60
    };

    for ( var n in t )
        t[n] && ret.push( t[n], n + "s".substr( t[n] < 2 ) );

    return ret.join(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 
**setTimeOut**(expression,milisecs)

where **expression** can be the function to be called when the time in **milisecs** is completed.

A good example manipulating several time counters can be found at:
http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/timer-set.php

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP wants functions to convert time in seconds to a string of h, m, s, etc...

Comment: Zack you are right, now before edition I can see what's the scope of the question

Answer (score 0):

It's not elegant, but should work:

```
function format_duration(elem) {
var num = parseInt($(elem).text());
var hours = 0;
var mins = 0;
var secs = 0;
while (num > 0) {
  if (num < 60) {
    secs += num;
    num = 0;
  }
  else if (num < 3600) {
    mins++;
    num -= 60;
  }
  else if (num < 86400) {
    hours++;
    num -= 3600;
  }
}
var rv = "";
if (hours > 0) {
    rv += hours+" hours ";
}
if (mins > 0) {
    rv += mins+" mins ";
}
if (secs > 0) { 
    rv += secs+" secs ";
}
$(elem).text(rv);
}
```

(updated to answer jquery usage too)

Answer (score 0):

nice Guffa.  You'll need to add some "floor" calls in there, though:

```
<snip>
    var h = Math.floor(t / 3600);
    t %= 3600;
    var m = Math.floor(t / 60);
<snip>
```