# How's a "duration picker" called and does it exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I'm looking for something like a "duration picker". Because googling "duration picker" doesn't give me any result, I would like to know if there is a technical name for it which can help in searching it. Time picker and Time Span picker doesn't bring anything helpful at the moment.

If something similar exists and someone can point me to that, it's ok instead of the technical name.

**Update 1:**

Sorry I completely forgot to explain what I mean by duration picker.
It's not a time picker, but a way to choose how much time will last doing something, not relative to a date. For example, cooking a given recipe will take (duration) 4 hours and 10 minutes. Traveling from here to there will take 4 days and 10 hours.

My basic idea is the possibility to configure the picker for the "bigger" unit to use (days probably), the duration will be expressed in seconds internally. So I can say `20 days and 23 hours and 0 minutes` or if the "bigger" unit is days (for a software development job for example), I can write `150 hours and 30 minutes and 0 seconds`.
It would be nice the option to hide some smaller fields, like minutes/seconds.

**Update 2:**

A very simple ui example:
[image]

Comment: That depends on what exactly your "duration picker" is supposed to do. We can't help you find the technical name if you won't give us a definition.

Comment: Have a look at knobs http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/ or bootstrap timepickers http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/

Comment: @Blazemonger: Sorry I'm stupid, I completely forget to explain what is... give me a second, updating the question.

Comment: @Archer: Sorry, updated the question to explain what I mean with "duration picker"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a good jQuery plugin or JS code for time durations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818830/is-there-a-good-jquery-plugin-or-js-code-for-time-durations)

Comment: Perhaps something like the range sliders in jQuery UI? http://jqueryui.com/slider/#rangemin

Comment: @James: They could be a part of the widget, but not the widget itself. Also I don't know the maximum (what if a job will last 2000 hours and I put a maximum of 100?)

Comment: @Bergi: It's different question, he is asking how to convert seconds (duration) to a readable format, while I'm asking a good way to **input duration to a form**, expressed in human format and which should be received by the server in seconds. Basically **it's the opposite**.

Comment: I just found this which could be adapted to incorporate a more UX friendly solution:
http://blog.nparashuram.com/2009/10/duration-input-component.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bootstrap Duration picker - [Github](https://github.com/koss-lebedev/bootstrap-duration-picker), [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-duration-picker).

Dependencies: jQuery and Bootstrap 3 (for styling only).

[image: demo screenshot]

Answer (score 15):

You could use a set of customized jQuery spinners

```
 $('#seconds').spinner({
     spin: function (event, ui) {
         if (ui.value >= 60) {
             $(this).spinner('value', ui.value - 60);
             $('#minutes').spinner('stepUp');
             return false;
         } else if (ui.value < 0) {
             $(this).spinner('value', ui.value + 60);
             $('#minutes').spinner('stepDown');
             return false;
         }
     }
 });
```

like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/xHzMw/1/

Comment: Digging through the web I reached the same answer. Thanks.

Comment: That's not really robust. you can for instance type 10 hours and 30535 minutes in those spinners.

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is old, but it seems like a satisfactory answer wasn't reached. I made a jQuery plugin for this exact use case, i'll post it for anyone that comes looking in the future like I did.

https://github.com/Tartarus762/jquery-duration-picker

Answer (score 0):

Its called just like you called it and exists at http://shop.ekerner.com/index.php/shop/javascript/duration-picker-detail

Comment: same problem as the above solution. Allows you to type in arbitrary large numbers in the minutes field

Comment: Does that matter? If the user knows the value is 4320 mins and doesnt want to convert it to hours then they can enter it in minutes.
For example machine running time may be known in hours or minutes.
Sounds like a feature ;) although, nice if after you entered > 59 mins its converted to hms. Ill add that next time near it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this jQuery plugin: http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Lightweight-Duration-Picker-Plugin-For-jQuery-Semantic-UI.html